DDD: Modelling different type of aggregates with some common behaviour and state (Not of transitioning nature)
I am trying to implement an HR management module wherein I have three 3 types of employees namely RegularEmployee, ReengagedEmployee, OutsourcedEmployee. All of them have some common properties like userId, name, address, mobile, dob, position. However, following are the special characteristics for each type of employee:
RegularEmployee: Regular employees in service

has retirement details
can be retired and therefore has behaviour executeRetirement()
position can be updated

ReengagedEmployee: Retired employees on extension

has retirement details
cannot be retired (as already retired)
position can be updated
has a contract start date and expiry date and therefore has behaviour expireContract()

OutsourcedEmployee: Employees engaged by a vendor

has a vendor reference
cannot be retired as he is managed by the vendor
position cannot be updated as position assigned against vendor
more functionalities may be added in future.

Position abstracts away the current place of posting of employee along with the chair he is holding in his office
All of the employees are users of the system and thus have userId property
The module will act as a dependency for other Bounded Contexts of a larger system. I am trying to implement the above system using Domain Driven Design concepts.
I was initially thinking of having three separate aggregates for RegularEmployee, ReengagedEmployee and OutsourcedEmployee but then I have to create separate repositories for each of the aggregate which does not seem elegant as I will have no way to simply find an employee by userId.
During online research, I came across the State Pattern wherein I have to define a common interface containing methods of every possible state dependent behavior and then each of the special cases (Regular, Reengaged, Outsourced) will implement all of those methods with NoOp bodies in case a behavior is unsupported (e.g. executeRetirement() in ReengagedEmployee should throw UnSupportedOperationException ??). That way I will have a common Aggregate interface on which I can base my repository.
My questions are,

Is my understanding of State Pattern correct?
Is it applicable to my use case?


"Is it applicable to my use case?" I'm more than one nine confident that you need a better understanding of how to decompose your system into aggregates.  Have you reviewed Mauro Servienti's talk?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hev65ozmYPI

I must admit that I am pretty new to DDD and will definitely look into the video that you shared. Thanks.
